# WordPress Loop and Google Maps Api query

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, google-maps

I have created a custom post with custom fields that give me the Lat and Lons of my locations.

I am needing a way to populate a map with all location marker showing for each location.

When a user selects a location the map needs to still show all locations on the map but the selected/active pin needs to change icon. I can only show one location at a time with the approach I have made below:

**How the user selects a location:**

```
<?php 
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'office_locations', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'order_by' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC'  );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

<option<?php echo (isset($_POST['selectedValue']) && $_POST['selectedValue'] == get_the_title() ? ' selected' : null) ?>><?php echo get_the_title();?></option>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

**I then get my selection location like so:**

```
<?php
if( $_POST['selectedValue'] == $_POST['selectedValue'] ){
    $location = $_POST['selectedValue'];
}
?>
```

**How the map utilises the data from the loop:**

I reopen the loop:

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'office_locations', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'title' => $location  ); $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

$lat = get_field( "lat" );  // Lattitude
$lon = get_field( "lon" ); // Longitude
```

**My Google map markers and mappings:**

```
function initMap() {

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
   zoom: 8,
   center: {lat: 53.381129, lng: -1.470085}
});

var icon = {
   url: "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/V/t/A/W/N/google-maps-gris-hi.png",
   scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(40, 50), // scaled size
   origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0), // origin
   anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
};

var <?php echo preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $location); ?> = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: {lat: <?php echo $lat; ?>, lng: <?php echo $lon; ?>},
   map: map,
   icon: icon
});
}
```

From here I am unsure on how to display all of the markers on the map at once, and then upon selection replacing the active icon/marker with another image.

Comment: Weird... Google Map APi is a JS API. All what's about your WordPress PHP is irrelevant. You want interactions with the map, once loaded and do not want the page to reload. Server scripts are executed for long and not to be considered after page load. You have to deal that from front-end.